# unable to run html code in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

> i just wanted to run html source code but when i enter html source
>   code to my text area and run it it displays only htmlcode as a string
>   but i wanted to run that code...............................

View page

```
@extends('layouts.theme')
@section('content')
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <form class="form-horizontal login-form" method="post" name="loginFrm" id="loginFrm">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="f" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <textarea name="txtinput" placeholder="Paste your html code here" class="col-sm-12" rows="20"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button type="submit" name="subBtn" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Format and Analyze</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div>
@if(count($htmlpagedata)>0)
       {{ htmlentities($htmlpagedata) }}
@endif
</div>
@stop
```

Controller

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class JHtmlParsing extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('input');
    }



    /**
     * Parse HTML Page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function parsehtml(Request $request)
    {
        $data=$request->get('txtinput');
        return view('input')->with('htmlpagedata',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include more detail on the problem. It's not entirely clear what your issue is from your question (as evidenced by the two separate answers).

Answer (score 0):

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.

If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

`{!! $variable !!}`

Answer (score 0):

you are using blade template so you need to extend .blade.
for example your file name is login then it should be

```
login.blade.php
```